# Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and 'System.Collection.Hashtable'

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, hashtable

Here i want to send hashtable to my user defined function ajaxSCall()
which require hashtable in last argument at '" & mData & "'
but it shows 
"Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and 'System.Collection.Hashtable'. "
Please help me what should i do

```
Public Shared Function diplayNoti(ByVal BtnLabel As String ,ByVal btnUrl As String, ByVal mData As Hashtable)

    scriptHtm= "<script>function(){ ajaxSCall('NL', 'mainDiv', '" & btnUrl & "','" & mData & "' )};</script>"

    Return scriptHtm
```

Comment: `.ToString()`? Maybe?

Comment: Are you trying to send the WHOLE hashtable?!

Comment: As Infer-On stated in his answer, please show the parameters expected by `ajaxSCall`.  You can't pass entire objects through script (text) like this.

Answer (score 1):

Your hashtable is a collection of key/value pairs so you should cast to string the desired key of your collection

[Hashtable Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx)

> Represents a collection of key/value pairs that are organized based on
>   the hash code of the key.

```
scriptHtm= "<script>function(){ ajaxSCall('NL', 'mainDiv', '" & btnUrl & "','" & CStr(mData("yourkey")) & "' )};</script>"
```

Comment: and how do you expect from btnUrl? :)

Comment: @Dhaval please edit your question with details of your ajaxSCall